# Get entire product page html block from outside Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, product, blocks

What I am trying to do is fairly straight forward.  I am basically trying to load the product block based on product ID.  Imagine an empty CMS page, and just fill it with the product block so it looks identical to the product page.  This is what I am trying to accomplish.  It needs to be done outside Magento, so calling a block like: `{{block type="catalog/product_single" product_id="1" template="catalog/product/singleproduct.phtml"}}` is out of the question.  This is what I have so far .. but I think I am trying to over-simplify this.   I know I am missing something obvious.

```
require_once '/blah/blah/blah/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$block = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options(); 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('22335');
$block->setProduct($product);
$block->getBlock('product');
echo $block->toHtml();
```

Does anyone have anything to add to this to make it work?

Comment: Do you only need the content block or do you need the entire page with doctype and all?

Comment: I only need the content block that's in the main wrapper ..  I don't need header/footer etc ..

Comment: If you need the entire product block why do you only create the options block?

Comment: Did you try recreating that call with getlayout createblock?

Answer (score 1):

Instantiating the Blocks this way might be a bad idea, but I think this should work. Do you have any problems?

```
require_once '/blah/blah/blah/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$block = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view_options');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('22335');
$block->setProduct($product);
echo $block->toHtml();
```